# How to get value from many2one-One2many in (new) product for a calculation in odoo 8?

Tags: relationship, one-to-many, odoo-8, many-to-one

I've made a custom field in product.template to select a product quality, based on a Many2one relationship with qualities.

```
qualities_id = field.Many2one(comodel_name="qualities", string="quality")
```

In the class: qualities there is a  One2Many relationship with the class: quality.supplier.

```
reseller_ids = fields.One2many('supplierinfo', 'product_qual_id', 'Supplier')
```

Here we can select a quality type e.g. ( *id=16 type=B321* ). This quality type (16) can have more then one supplier. So in supplierinfo we have the field product_qual_id (**id = 16**) that holds multi suppliers (**id = 24, 25, 26**)

```
product_qual_id = fields.Many2one('qualities', 'Quality Template')
```

Supplierinfo holds suppliers and each supplier holds more then one quantity and price. There is a relationship between supplierinfo and supplier prices using the field suppinfo_id.

```
pricelist_ids = fields.One2many('supplierprice', 'suppinfo_id', 'Supplier Price')
```

Because of this relationship, supplierprice: suppinfo, holds more then one quantity and corresponding price based on supplierinfo_id. Field that holds these records:

```
suppinfo_id = fields.Many2one('supplierinfo', 'Supplier information')
```

---

**Qualities** = ( *id=16 type=B321* ). This quality type (16) can have more then one supplier. So in **supplierinfo** we have the field product_qual_id (id = 16) that holds multi suppliers (**id = 24**, 25, 26) where Record id: 24 in relation to **supplierprice** has multi qty and prices:

1. supplierprice id=30 **supplierinfo id=24** qty=200, price=285
2. supplierprice id=31 supplierinfo id=24 qty=300, price=265
3. supplierprice id=32 supplierinfo id=24 qty=500, price=248

With additional automation, I need the **price** from **supplierprice**, based on (less or more) quantity in the main product. (**product.template, price**). Can anyone push me in the right direction. How can I get the price from supplierprice into a (new) field in my product.template?

I've added an image of the relationship model.
[relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE8pk.jpg)

Comment: Hi, im a bit confussed with the new classes you made, where do you need that price?, from what i understood you want a dynamical price that differs for the quantity in product.template? that quantity is for the purchase order that you made and i dont think that you should relate it to the product, unless you use that on the purchase order.

Comment: @dccdany, Hi, I know its confusing. I'm calculating the price for a product based on size of cardboard (L x W x H)= m2

Comment: @dccdany, Hi, I know its confusing. I'm calculating the price for a product based on size of cardboard (L x W x H)= m2, quality of cardboard and supplier prices. The result of these calculations will be the product price per piece. I'm selecting a certain quality. This quality is supplied by more then one supplier. Each supplier has more then one quotes. So i need the price from a supplier based on minimum quantity, deliver delay and price. This combination will give me the best price that I can use in my calculations.